# Can a microservice publish and consume to/from same kafka topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka

Can a micro service(single pod) publish and consume to/from same kafka topic?

Here is the scenario

A micro service named "service1" is consuming message from kafka topic "A".

Second service named "service2" publishes the message on kafka topic "A" which is processed by "service 1" and inserts the data in DB.

Third micro service name "service3" is publishing message to kafka topic "A" which is consumed by "service1" and updates DB record which was inserted in the previous step.

"service1" checks DB for certain update and generates event to check DB update until condition is met. DB update "servcie1" is looking for will be completed only when "service1" processes message from "service3"
if (condition not met)
Publish message to kafka topic "A"(Event generated so that service1 can go back to consume message instead of timing out. The generated message is received by "service1" again and processes it to check DB)

Issue: In this case once "Service1" starts producing message, message from "service3" is not seen. "Service1" goes on in a loop of publishing and consuming the message it has produced.

Why message from "Servcie3" is not seen although it is being produced every minute?

Note: micro service is written in python and confluent kafka is being used.

Tried scaling up the number of pod and the message is seen from "Servcie3" and service 1 comes out of the loop.

Scaling up is not viable option here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue. Will keep in mind for next time.

Comment: @KumarRahul Do you have any idea about this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/75756053/3946958 . Please check it once

Answer (score 0):

setting the following kafka consumer setting worked

```
"auto.offset.reset": "earliest"
```